# Playa total_parents tag vs search parameter

Tags: playa, search, parameters

I'm using the `{exp:playa:total_parents}` tag with a `search:comment_matrix_row='={segment_3}'` parameter, but it appears to ignore the search-parameter. Is that expected behavior?

Thanks,

- Steven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that’s expected. The `search:field_name=` parameters are actually handled by Channel Entries, which Playa calls at the end of `{exp:playa:parents}` and `{exp:playa:children}` only.

We should probably update the Playa docs to list out specifically which tags `total_parents`, `total_children`, `parent_ids`, and `child_ids` actually support, as their list is much smaller than `parents` and `children`.

Comment: That would be great. Even greater would be to pass those parameters to total_parents too :). Found an ugly hack involving js for now though!